# Determine if collection.forEach is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to print all data from a collection and some research has shown the best way to do that is

```
DB.collection('users').find({}).each( (err, i) => {
   console.log(i);
});
```

Which is great, but running a console.log after this loop will print before hand, and I need to run something after all items are returned.

If I can instead retrieve all documents at once, that would solve my issue, otherwise I need to determine when this loop is complete, then run some code to handle the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a bit of puzzling to figure out, as the MongoDB API directly doesn't directly map on expected Node concepts.

Regardless, MongoDB's find method returns a [cursor object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html). This cursor object does in fact implement `each` (as well as other helpful methods like `toArray`.)

However, the [callback](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4) takes *two* parameters, not just one. *[Edit: the question used to have only one parameter in the callback, a transcription mistake by OP]*

```
DB.collection('users').find({}).each( (error, i) => {
   console.log(i);
});
```

It's Node convention that the first parameter of a callback be an error object, for error handling purposes. The next parameters are your actual data - in this case the record from Mongo.

Comment: Yes, and I'm actually doing this, idk why I didn't in my example given, but that's not the problem I'm having, The problem I'm having is having something run after all results are returned. I have no problem returning the items.

Comment: then maybe use toArray instead of each? It take a callback with an error and an array of returned records, instead of each record one by one.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!